# Adding doctype modifies layout

Tags: html, css

I am presently updating my website. However, when I add !DOCTYPE the layout of my left menu is not the same)

I know that I am not the first persons to ask about this on this forum, but I didn't find the answer to my problem.

My understanding is that my CSS is the problem so here the code I use.

```css
.gh {background:#C81919; text-align:right; vertical-align:top; padding-top: 20px;}
.gauche {background:#C81919; WIDTH:180; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; font-size:11pt;         font-weight:bold; color:EADBC6; text-align:right; vertical-align:top;}
.dh {WIDTH:640; padding: 20px 0px 15px 1px; vertical-align:top; font-size:13pt;}
.droit {WIDTH:600; padding-left:41px; font-size:13pt; color:black; line-height:28px; text-align:justify; vertical-align:top;}
sup {line-height: 0;}
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;}
li {margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;}
#liste a:hover {background:url("marble1.gif"); color: C81919;}
#liste a {background-color: 000000; display: block; width: 180; padding: 6px 6px; color: EADBC6; text-decoration: none;}
#liste2 a {display: block; width: 180; padding: 2px 6px; color: EADBC6; text-decoration: none;}
#liste2 a:hover {background:url("marble1.gif"); color: C81919;}
```

Comment: We also need to see your document, and doctype.

Comment: Quick thought is the capitalized `WIDTH` properties.

Comment: So... what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctypes control how the browser understands your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It may close off some features of the browser, or open up others. As a result, you need to ensure you are writing clean and well-formed code. Not only does this ensure the browser will be less-confused about your code, but it makes it easier for you to manage your expectations.

While your above code doesn't use any edge features, it does have several issues:

1. `WIDTH:180` You need to put a unit here. Don't assume `px` will be provided for you.
2. `background-color: 000000`, `color:EADBC6` Hex values need to start with `#`.

These are just a couple examples of things that could effect your layout and presentation.

Another important topic is the `box-model`, which is the way in which the browser calculates the overall width of an element by adding content-width, padding, borders, and margins. Browsers in history have figured this differently in the past, but today we can unite their understanding with `box-sizing` in CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

This instructs all modern browsers to set their box model (for all elements) in accordance with the border of the box itself. However, this feature *is* a newer feature and will require a standards doctype. So to ensure things are working properly in the majority of browsers, use the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Lastly, be sure this is the very first thing in your code. Nothing can precede this, or some browsers may invalidate the doctype as a result.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan for your prompt and detailed answer. Your explanations were clear and help me out.